# c# custom auto-property setter not allowing me to massage the value

Tags: c#

Can you do something like this in an auto-property?

```
public byte[] bytearr 
{
    get { return value; } 
    set 
    { 
        (value.Length %2 == 0 ? 
            value : 
            new List<byte>(value).Add((byte)0)
        ).ToArray(); 
    } 
}
```

Note the right hand of the ':' in the ternary.

If you can what is wrong in my syntax? `new List<>` isn't enjoying that I'm trying to tack on the necessary `.ToArray()`.

But I don't seem to be able to but multiple execution lines of code in an setter auto-property.

I don;t think I've ever come across wanting to massage the fields value in it's setter like this before.  But how long has it been since I declared the backing field?  I don't know.

I've tried quite a few things.  And it isn't any problem if I have to declare the private field.  At this point I'm just curious more than anything because it seems like I could be able to do this without actually declaring the field.

Thanks.

Comment: That´s not auto-(implemented-) property, it is actually *fully* implemented.

Comment: And you are not doing any assignment in there - so any values you create are being thrown away... You will have to declare the backing field, or where are you storing the data?

Comment: Ohhhh... I understand - you are trying to avoid creating a temporary variable for the list - that's nothing to do with auto-properties. You are looking for `collection initializers`.

Comment: Yeah.  When I do `value=` I get a stack overflow.  Can you really reassign value?  But if I do create the backing field I don't have any problems

Comment: That´s exactly what you *have* to do. Of course you could re-assign `value`, but that variable isn´t what you think it is. Actually it´s just an internal variable of that name that - if reassigned - won´t change your actual property. However you want to assign its value to a *new* backing.field, e.g. `_bytearr`. There´s no way around declaring this backing field (in case of an auto-implemented property this field is also generated, but not accessable at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be looking for [collection initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.spx#Collection%20initializers), not auto-properties.

This is what will allow you to create a list and add values to it inline.

```
public byte[] bytearr 
{
    get { return value; } 
    set 
    { 
        somePrivateField = (value.Length %2 == 0 ? 
            value : 
            new List<byte> { value, (byte)0 }
        ).ToArray(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You are right.  But again I was trying to do without declaring the backing field.  What I'm trying to do today in a setter I probably had been (and probably should be again today) doing in a `collection initializer`.  Thanks man

Comment: @user2367083 You have to declare a backing field for the `byte[]`. You don't have to declare a private field for the List. It's *really* unclear what you are trying to say though, as you are mixing up two concepts, across two separate lines of code...

Comment: @RB what happens if value is null?

Comment: This code will not compile. One - variable somePrivateField is not declared anywhere. Two - `new List<byte>` can not contain an array of bytes and a zero.

Comment: `value` doesn't exist in the getter

Comment: @RB. you win.  If you define a setter body you have to define a getter body.  But `get` doesn't have `value` so become forced to declare the backing field.  `get` does have `bytearr` but returning that is a stack overflow. I didn't want to do the backing field so I moved the logic to the collection initializer.  Thanks man

Comment: That won´t compile at all. In your setter you set the value for a field (not shown), which you don´t even use in the getter which is weird but not a problem for the compiler. However there´s no `value` in the getter. Furthermore in the setter `value` is of type `byte[]` which can´t be added to a `List<byte>`, you would need a call to `List<T>.AddRange` followed by a call to `List<T>.Add` to add an array *and* a single value to the list.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using private field here as following.

To me it looks like you are checking if number of items in the incoming array is odd or even. If it's even you accept the array as it is but if it's odd you are adding a zero to the end of the array before accepting it.

```
private byte[] byteArray;
public byte[] ByteArray
{
    get { return this.byteArray; } 
    set
    {
        this.SetByteArray(value);
    }
}

private void SetByteArray(byte[] value)
{
    if (value.Length % 2 == 0)
    {
        this.byteArray = value;
    }
    else
    {
        var x = new List<byte>(value);
        x.Add(0);
        this.byteArray = x.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Fixing it.. the code by OP itself is not compiling. So not sure what should be the logic in setter.

Comment: @johnny5 You should really explain why it won't work! The issue is that the call to `Add` is a `void` method, so can't be used in the RHS of the ternary as he has used it.

Comment: @RB yeah I know I explained that in the answer I wrote

Answer (score 0):

You can´t provide an implementation to a property and not declare a backing-field for it where you store the value obtained from the setter. In fact the compiler will automatically create a private backing field for you in case of an auto-implemented property. However this field is hidden to the outside and you can´t access it (you could using reflection, but this is not the point here).

So your property should definitly look like this:

```
private byte[] _bytearr;
public byte[] bytearr 
{
    get { return _bytearr; } 
    set 
    { 
        _bytearr = (value.Length %2 == 0 ? 
            value : 
            new List<byte> { value, (byte)0 }
        ).ToArray(); 
    } 
}
```

Furthermore the `value`-keyword exists only within a properties setter and gets the name assigned to that property. As a property is nothing but a set of a get- and a set-method this variable only exists within the latter. So changing its content won´t have any effect on your actual data, it´s just internal to the setter.

An auto-implemented property however does not have any logic in the getter and setter, so it´s just this:

```
public MyProperty { get; set; }
```

However the compiler will change this to:

```
private _MyProperty;
public int Numerator
{
    get { return _MyProperty ; }
    set { _MyProperty = value; }
}
```

which will further become similar to this:

```
private _MyProperty;
public int get_MyProperty() 
{ 
    return _MyProperty ; 
}
public void set_MyProperty() 
{ 
    this._MyProperty = value; 
}
```

EDIT: As Johny correctly pointed out you can´t use two different return-values with a ternary operator unless one of them is of a derived type of the other and you cast it appropriately. Thus your properties setter body should be similar to that one given in Chetan Ranpariya´s answer.

Comment: This will not work, you cannot have a ternary using two different types

Comment: @johnny5 You´re right, I completely missed the logic within the setter as I only wanted to point out the meaning and syntax of properties. Added a note.